# Adding individual column search on seprate row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to add text boxes to search my datatables (which i have done) but the position of them is in the same `<Tr>` as my row titles.

As you can see here:

[image]

But I want to make the inputs go on the seperate row so they're split like so:

[image]

My code:

```
if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('.table')) {
    $('.table thead th').each( function (i) {
        var title = $('.table thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).after('<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" data-index="'+i+'" />' );
    } );

    var table = $('.table').DataTable( {
        paging:         false
    } );


    $( table.table().container() ).on( 'keyup', 'thead input', function () {
        table
            .column( $(this).data('index') )
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
    } );
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create another row.

```js
var ths = $('.table thead th');
var searchTr = $('<tr></tr>');
searchTr.insertAfter(ths.parents('tr'));
searchTr.append(ths.map(function (i) {
  var title = $(this).text();
  return $('<td><input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" data-index="'+i+'" /></td>')[0];
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header1</th><th>Header2</th><th>Header3</th><th>Header4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Content1</th><th>Content2</th><th>Content3</th><th>Content4</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```